# How to handle "No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method"

Tags: apex, batch

I am facing a strange scenario.

I have a method which I need to test.

There is a line in a method like this:-

```
if( items.size() > INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE ) {
    BillingInvoiceBatch b = new BillingInvoiceBatch(records);
    Database.executeBatch(b, INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE);
}
```

In my test class , I am creating 3 items and setting INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE to 2.
And I want test coverage for this if block. So I want to start a batch.
Problem is because execute batch has a scope mentioned i.e INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE , it will try to create two batches.
If I create number of items equal to INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE it wont enter the if block.

How to test this if block ?

Comment: Just a though, but couldn't you just create two test methods? One for each condition, and then together they'd create the test coverage you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `if` condition to as follows

```
if(items.size() > INVOICE_BATCH_SIZE || Test.isRunningTest()) {
    // conditional logic
}
```

This way you can bypass this condition from your test code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there has to be test coverage for the else part too and this will always enter the if part

Comment: ok, can you please post the else part as well?

Comment: nothing special there in the else part ... just updating some records ....

Comment: Any particular reason for creating 3 items? Are you creating records at once in @TestSetup or in separate test methods?